# Galaxy S4 not receiving official update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, ota-update

> Edit: (Not a duplicate) This question is not related to another
>   question on the forum, this is related also to android 4.3 jelly bean,
>   and furthermore I have provided my serial number of Galaxy S4, so read
>   the question fully.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 i9300XXUAMDK, and I still have 4.2.2 Jelly Bean. I don't understand why I am not even getting the 4.3 Jelly Bean update when 4.4 KitKat is rolling out for Samsung S4. Does someone have any clue?

Comment: It almost certainly depends on your carrier.

Comment: Look here: http://live.samsung-updates.com/index.php?device=GT-I9505  Only ONE carrier has the 4.4.2 update yet. As the others said it depends on your country and carrier and device. You can be patient and wait or try an official firware for another region (available on Sammobile) or if rooted you could flash a KitKat custom ROM.

Comment: What about Jelly Bean 4.3?

Comment: I know that some carriers in the past have opted to skip Android versions. Who is your carrier? They are the ones holding up the update. Unless you're willing to chance sideloading the update (which has its own sort of risk) you're stuck.

Comment: This version is the Indian one, so updates for this phone till now are 4.2.2 so that means I am stuck with this one or I'll add that with custom ROM!